# How to get the duplicated items in the array and select one of them to be presented in the new array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am building custom permissions system for different sections of a Laravel application.
I have an array of arrays and maybe there is a duplication in the `section_id` value but with different `permission` value.
for example i have `section_id => 10` exists 3 times here with different 3 `permission`.

```
[
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 10
      "permission" => "B"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 22
      "permission" => "A"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 10
      "permission" => "A"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 13
      "permission" => "B"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 18
      "permission" => "B"
    ]
    5 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 10
      "permission" => "C"
    ]
]
```

Now I need to get only the highest permission level available in the array for the duplicated section `section => 10`

A,B and C are the permissions levels so the priority for A then B then C for the same section , the final result should be like this

```
[    
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 10
      "permission" => "A"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 22
      "permission" => "A"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 13
      "permission" => "B"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "section_id" => 18
      "permission" => "B"
    ]
]
```

Comment: You possibly generating this as output from your database and models through some controller. It will be better to achieve what you want at that level before this output. Kindly share the database structure, models and controller code.

Comment: @ElishaSenoo it will not be easy for me to achieve it from the DB because it's very complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections using sortBy(), unique() and values() chain in this way:

```
public function test() {
    $p = [
        [
            'section_id' => 10,
            'permission' => 'B'
        ],
        [
            'section_id' => 22,
            'permission' => 'A'
        ],
        [
            'section_id' => 10,
            'permission' => 'A'
        ],
        [
            'section_id' => 13,
            'permission' => 'B'
        ],
        [
            'section_id' => 18,
            'permission' => 'B'
        ],
        [
            'section_id' => 10,
            'permission' => 'C'
        ],
    ];

    $collection = collect($p);
    $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
        return ord($product['permission']);
    })->unique('section_id')->values()->all();
    dd($p, $sorted);
}
```

Outputs

```
    array:6 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 10
        "permission" => "B"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 22
        "permission" => "A"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 10
        "permission" => "A"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 13
        "permission" => "B"
      ]
      4 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 18
        "permission" => "B"
      ]
      5 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 10
        "permission" => "C"
      ]
    ]
    array:4 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 22
        "permission" => "A"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 10
        "permission" => "A"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 13
        "permission" => "B"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [▼
        "section_id" => 18
        "permission" => "B"
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: what if i want to sort by permission B , also what if have only B,C only and i want to get C

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myArray = array( 
   ["section_id" => 10, "permission" => "B"],
   ["section_id" => 22, "permission" => "A"],
   ["section_id" => 10, "permission" => "A"],
   ["section_id" => 13, "permission" => "B"],
   ["section_id" => 18, "permission" => "B"],
   ["section_id" => 10, "permission" => "C"]);

$sectionArr  = array_column($myArray, 'section_id');
$permissionArr = array_column($myArray, 'permission');

array_multisort($sectionArr, SORT_ASC, $permissionArr, SORT_ASC, $myArray);
$newArray = array();
$tempSection = array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $singleArray){
  if(!in_array($singleArray['section_id'], $tempSection)){
      $tempSection[] = $singleArray['section_id'];
      $newArray[] = ["section_id" => $singleArray['section_id'], "permission" => $singleArray['permission']];
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```